# Web performance load test error on Application insight for the site associated with Microsoft world wide learning group

Tags: load-testing

We are in the process of implementing Application insight for monitoring the sites related to Microsoft Worldwide Learning group. To do so we are creating webtests for our sites using VS Enterprise 2017 so that we can upload *.webtest files to Application insights on Azure. Here we are getting below error for sign in using WSFedAuth while running webtests for our site on Application insight. This webtest script runs as expected on our local computer but the same is getting failed on Application insight. I can share the webtest script as well if required. Any thoughts or suggestions to fix this issue will be really appreciated. Other simple webtest scripts (without sign in scenarios) for example our Home Page is running perfectly fine on App insight.

We have used below user for sign in and please let me know and share your email address if you require password to access the below site to simulate the sign in scenario from your end.

https://mpn.int.mlx.microsoft.com?whr=uri:MicrosoftAccount
User:mlxstudent1@live.com

Error Details:
Web test result:
9 primary requests, 0 dependant requests and 0 conditional rules failed

Extraction Rule Error (subtype 'ExtractText') occured at 03/05/2019 00:16:54 (UTC) for Uri 'https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1551745013&rver=6.7.6643.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fapi.bvt.mlxma.microsoft.com%2fWsFedAuth%2fRPSLogOn%3fwa%3dwsignin1.0%26wtrealm%3dhttps%3a%252F%252Fapi.int.mlx.microsoft.com%252F%26wctx%3drm%253D1%2526id%253D50afe0c9-05c9-422d-9102-02780276a062%2526ru%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fapi.int.mlx.microsoft.com%25252FPartner%25252FPermissions%25252F79711859-8596-4F4A-99C6-E7054FA85A0F%25252F%25253Fwhr%25253Duri%25253AMicrosoftAccount%252526r%25253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fmpn.int.mlx.microsoft.com%25252F%25253Fwhr%25253Duri%25253AMicrosoftAccount%26wct%3d2019-03-05T00%3a16%3a53Z%26whr%3duri%3aMicrosoftAccount&id=294747&contextid=055885AFBCE594AE&bk=1551745014&pid=0', step #9 with the error 'StartsWith text was not found in the response'.%

Thanks
Santosh

Comment: The error message is clear, the "StartWith" text of an extraction rule was not found in the response. Your question does not show that "StartWith" text so we cannot see whether something similar was in the response.

Comment: I suggest running the test on another "local" computer when logged in as a different user than on the first "local" computer. You may need to record a new web test, just to do the login, and see how the new one compares to the original.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands, it is very difficult for us to help you. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit the question accordingly. If you are asking us to debug you code, please include the code. This is called a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); ensure you have sample inputs, outputs, and, if any, errors included. Consider these, before posting any question. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, we could see the 'StartsWith' as part of extraction rule. Regarding running the test on another local computer, yes we ran on another local computer as well. It worked as expected, But failing with above error on Application insight.

Comment: I know the StartsWith text is in the extraction rule, but it is not shown in your question, nor is the response which should contain that text. The problem sounds to me like a username/ password/ authentication mismatch. I have solved related questions by adding plugins to the webtest and have them call `AddCommentToResult` (perhaps several times) to add debugging information. The information I would show is stuff not easily seen in the normal web test results. I would run the test with a small number of virtual users and few iterations to avoid having too much data to analyze.